# Redis zrange sort value as integer

Tags: redis

Since zrange "Lexicographical order is used for elements with equal score" how do I go around this issue?

For example:

```
zadd s 0 1
zadd s 0 2
zadd s 0 10
zadd s 0 3

zrange s 0 4
1) 1
2) 10
3) 2
4) 3
```

How do I make it sort like this (while ofc honor the score):

```
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
4) 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter the lexicographic order.

However, you could store a value whose lexicographic order matches with numerical order. For instance instead of storing:

```
1
2
12
15
122
321
```

you could store:

```
A1
A2
B12
B15
C122
C321
```

The first letter is just a code to indicate the number of digits of the numerical value (A=1, B=2, etc ...), so that numerical and lexicographic order is the same. The client application can easily add/remove this prefix at store/retrieve time.

```
 zadd s 0 A1
 zadd s 0 A2
 zadd s 0 B10
 zadd s 0 A3

 zrange s 0 4
 1) "A1"
 2) "A2"
 3) "A3"
 4) "B10"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to figure out a way like this, but didn't think of this one!